# How can I translate z3::expr(bv_val) into a bit representation of a number?

Tags: c++, z3, symbolic-execution

I am trying to translate `Z3::expr` into a bit representation of a number in order to find out how many bits `1` the number contains and if the number of bits `1` is even, then I raise the flag.

I wrote the implementation below, but it doesn't work the way I need.

```
static inline bool calculate_parity(z3::context& z3c, z3::expr** even_bits, z3::expr** dst)
{
    z3::expr num = z3c.bv_val(42, 64); // 42 in 64-bit binary representation
    for (int i = 31; i >= 0; i--) {
        z3::expr bit = num.extract(i, i);
        std::cout << bit << " ";
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;

    return true;
}
```

The implementation of the task can be compared with raising the `pf` flag in the x86_64 assembler.

Something like this:

```
static inline void translate_add(z3::context& z3c, x8664_ctx& old_state, x8664_ctx& new_state, ZydisDisassembledInstruction ins)
{
    if (ins.info.operand_count_visible == 2)
    {
        auto& op1 = ins.operands[0];
        auto& op2 = ins.operands[1];

        z3::expr e1 = **Z3SystemTranslateFuncs::get_val_expr(z3c, old_state, op1);
        z3::expr e2 = **Z3SystemTranslateFuncs::get_val_expr(z3c, old_state, op2);
        z3::expr** dst = Z3SystemTranslateFuncs::get_val_expr(z3c, new_state, op1);

        *dst = new z3::expr(z3c, e1 + e2);
        
        new_state.zf = new z3::expr(**dst == 0);
        new_state.of = new z3::expr(((e1 ^ e2) & 0x7FFFFFFF) == 0 && ((e1 ^ **dst) & 0x7FFFFFFF) != 0);
        new_state.cf = new z3::expr((e1 + e2).simplify() < e1.simplify());

        ***new_state.pf = new z3::expr(z3c.bool_val(Z3SystemTranslateFuncs::calculate_parity(z3c, dst, dst)));***

        new_state.sf = new z3::expr(**dst < 0); 

        z3::expr bit3 = (e1 + e2).extract(3, 3);
        z3::expr bit4 = (e1 + e2).extract(4, 4);
        new_state.af = new z3::expr((bit3 ^ bit4) != 0);
    }
    else
        throw std::exception("bad operand count in translate_add function");
}
```

Comment: Do you get an error? Does it not compile? What exactly is the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The basic c++ function to compute the parity would be:

```cpp
// Check if #of 1's is even. This can be achieved
// by xor'ing all the bits, if even 1's then result will be 0
// otherwise it'll be 1
expr parity64(context &ctx, expr x) {
    expr res = ctx.bv_val(0, 1);

    for (int i = 0; i < 64; i++)
    {
        res = res ^ x.extract(i, i);
    }

    return res;
}
```

Looks like you're trying to do this in the context of a larger framework. You might be able to translate the above to that system, or you should tag your question with appropriate tags so people who are familiar with that system can answer your question. (If there are any on stack-overflow, that is!)